# Sort array Alphabetically- Angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, filter, angular-ngmodel, angular-filters

I have my result showing here

```
<div ng-repeat="o in vm.gridOptions.data | filter:filt | oderBy : 'title'">
    <span>{{o.title}}</span>
</div>
```

which shows

```
<div ng-repeat="o in vm.gridOptions.data">
    <span>aaa</span>
    <span>ggg</span>
    <span>ccc</span>
    <span>bbb</span>
</div>
```

I have a select dropdown. I should able to sort my result alphabetally after  i select '`Alphabetical`' option

```
<select ng-model="filt">
    <option value="-1">vsf</option>
    <option>Alphabetical</option>
    <option>sccc</option>                                    
</select>
```

Initially i have put orderBy:'title'. but this should happen after i select dropdown. how to achieve this ?

Comment: `Alphabetical`  is any column of your array?

Comment: No... Alphabetical is just an option from select dropdown..

Comment: @Matarishvan did you checked my answer ?

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

`<div ng-repeat="o in vm.gridOptions.data | filter:filt | oderBy : filt?'title':''">`

Answer (score 1):

```
<select ng-model="filt">
  <option>Alphabetical</option>
  <option>k</option>
</select>
<p ng-if="filte=(filt=='Alphabetical')?'':'o.title' "></p>
<div ng-repeat="o in vm.gridOptions.data | orderBy: filte">
<span>{{o.title}}</span>
```

Answer (score 1):

It is better if you do the filtering and sorting in `controller`.
You can change the `Array.prototype.sort()` function as per your requirement

Controller

```
$scope.data=[{
    "title" : "gggg"
},{
    "title" : "cccc"
},{
    "title" : "zzzz"
},{
    "title" : "aaaa"
}];
$scope.sortvalue = "None";

$scope.changeSortOrder = function()
{
  if($scope.sortvalue == "Alphabetically")
  {
    $scope.data.sort(function(a, b){
      if(a.title < b.title) return -1;
      if(a.title > b.title) return 1;
      return 0;
    });
  }
}
```

HTML

```
<div ng-controller="myCtrl">
    <div ng-repeat="o in data">
      <span>{{o.title}}</span>
    </div>
    <div>
     <select ng-model="sortvalue" ng-change="changeSortOrder()">
      <option value="None">Select an option</option>
      <option value="Alphabetically">Alphabetically</option>
     </select>
    </div>
  </div>
```

**[FULL EXAMPLE](https://jsfiddle.net/Kunalh/7p4k41Lf/3/)**

[Here](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_array_sort.asp) is a list of examples that uses `Array.prototype.sort()` to sort arrays

Answer (score 1):

**Try this way :**

```js
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

myApp.controller('MyCtrl',function($scope) {
    $scope.data = [{
        "title" : "aaa"
    },{
        "title" : "ggg"
    },{
        "title" : "ccc"
    },{
        "title" : "bbb"
    }];
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="MyCtrl">
  <select ng-model="filt">
    <option value="-1">vsf</option>
    <option value="title">Alphabetical</option>
    <option>sccc</option>                                    
  </select>
  <div ng-repeat="o in data | orderBy:filt">
   {{o.title}}
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Very simple..

You want to sort Alphabetically.. means u have to pass value as `'title'` to your option `'Alphabetical'`.
because based on 'title' the result will sort

```
<select ng-model="filt">
    <option value="-1">vsf</option>
    <option value="title">Alphabetical</option>
    <option>sccc</option>                                    
</select>
```

Then in your div

```
<div ng-repeat="o in vm.gridOptions.data | orderBy:filt">
```

`orderBy: filt` will execute only for your `option value='title'`. That is where sorting happens